# Can anyone identify this tree please - I'm stuck!

Tags: identification, trees

I'm really stumped (!) by what this tree is - can anyone out there help me identify it please?

Its located in the UK, in North London, photo taken today - 27.03.2020

Thanks for your time!

Sean

[image]

Comment: Welcome, Sean! For an identification, it’s helpful to have photos of details in addition to the overall view (which interestingly many uses forget), so the bark the leaves, buds and flowers if available... the tag “identification” gives a few pointers. Apart from that, taking the [tour] and browsing through the [help] should get you started in the right directions.